# Почему при запуске приложения появляется еще одно окно?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qstackedwidget, qstackedlayout

После добавления некоторых строк кода появилась проблема: при запуске приложения на секунду появляется другое окно.

Не могу понять что я делаю не так?

Проблема появляется после вот этих строк кода:

```
        self.form1_box = QWidget()
        self.form2_box = QWidget()
        self.stacked_form_box = QStackedLayout()
        self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.form1_box)
        self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.form2_box)
        self.form1_box.setLayout(la_le_box)
        self.form2_box.setLayout(la_le_box2)
```

А вот и сам код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLayout, \
    QFormLayout, QStackedLayout
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        def _consumptiontab(self):

            # макет кнопок Human and Population
            type_polutation_box = QHBoxLayout()
            type_polutation_box.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
            type_polutation_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            type_polutation_box.setSpacing(0)
            type_polutation_box.setObjectName("Type Population Button")
            # макет лейблов для формы
            pop_label_box = QVBoxLayout()   # 1 форма
            pop_label_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            pop_label_box.setObjectName("Labels with type population")
            pop_label_box2 = QVBoxLayout()  # 2 форма
            pop_label_box2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            pop_label_box2.setObjectName("Labels with type population2")
            # макет строк редактирования для формы
            pop_le_box = QVBoxLayout()   # 1 форма
            pop_le_box.setContentsMargins(0, 5, 0, -1)
            pop_le_box.setSpacing(10)
            pop_le_box.setObjectName("Population type edit line")
            pop_le_box2 = QVBoxLayout()  # 2 форма
            pop_le_box2.setContentsMargins(0, 5, 0, -1)
            pop_le_box2.setSpacing(10)
            pop_le_box2.setObjectName("Population type edit line2")
            # 2 формы для лейблов и едитов
            la_le_box = QFormLayout()    # 1 форма
            la_le_box.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
            la_le_box.setFieldGrowthPolicy(la_le_box.FieldsStayAtSizeHint)
            la_le_box.setRowWrapPolicy(la_le_box.DontWrapRows)
            la_le_box.setLabelAlignment(Qt. AlignRight | Qt. AlignTrailing
                                        | Qt. AlignVCenter)
            la_le_box.setFormAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading
                                       | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            la_le_box.setContentsMargins(50, 70, 50, 80)
            la_le_box.setVerticalSpacing(3)
            la_le_box.setObjectName("type population form")
            la_le_box2 = QFormLayout()   # 2 форма
            la_le_box2.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
            la_le_box2.setFieldGrowthPolicy(la_le_box2.FieldsStayAtSizeHint)
            la_le_box2.setRowWrapPolicy(la_le_box2.DontWrapRows)
            la_le_box2.setLabelAlignment(Qt. AlignRight | Qt. AlignTrailing
                                         | Qt. AlignVCenter)
            la_le_box2.setFormAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading
                                        | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            la_le_box2.setContentsMargins(50, 70, 50, 80)
            la_le_box2.setVerticalSpacing(3)
            la_le_box2.setObjectName("type population form2")
            # макет для форм
            self.form1_box = QWidget()
            self.form2_box = QWidget()
            self.stacked_form_box = QStackedLayout()
            self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.form1_box)
            self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.form2_box)
            self.form1_box.setLayout(la_le_box)
            self.form2_box.setLayout(la_le_box2)
            # макет для кнопок и формы
            buttons_form = QVBoxLayout()
            buttons_form.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
            buttons_form.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, 0, -1)
            buttons_form.setSpacing(5)
            buttons_form.setObjectName("Buttons and form type population")

            self.people_btn = QPushButton(QIcon(':Population.webp'), '')
            sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
            sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
            sizePolicy.setVerticalPolicy(0)
            sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
                self.people_btn.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            self.people_btn.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
            self.people_btn.setMaximumSize(50, 25)
            self.people_btn.setObjectName("people_btn")
            self.people_btn.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.stacked_form_box.setCurrentIndex(0))

            self.house_btn = QPushButton(QIcon(':3d_storage.png'), '')
            sizePolicy2 = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
            sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(1)
            sizePolicy2.setVerticalPolicy(0)
            sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(
                self.house_btn.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            self.house_btn.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
            self.house_btn.setMaximumSize(50, 25)
            self.house_btn.setObjectName("house_btn")
            self.house_btn.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.stacked_form_box.setCurrentIndex(1))

            type_polutation_box.addWidget(self.people_btn)
            type_polutation_box.addWidget(self.house_btn)
            type_polutation_box.setStretch(1, 1)
            buttons_form.addLayout(type_polutation_box)

            valid = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9 .,]{15}")
            val = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(valid)

            for i in range(7):      # заполнение лейблами 1 формы
                pic_laybel = QLabel()
                pic = QPixmap(":1_Farmers.webp")
                pic_laybel.setPixmap(pic)
                pic_laybel.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
                pic_laybel.setMaximumSize(40, 40)
                pic_laybel.setScaledContents(True)
                pop_label_box.addWidget(pic_laybel)

            for i in range(7):      # заполнение лейблами 2 формы
                pic_laybel = QLabel()
                pic = QPixmap(":2_Workers.webp")
                pic_laybel.setPixmap(pic)
                pic_laybel.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
                pic_laybel.setMaximumSize(40, 40)
                pic_laybel.setScaledContents(True)
                pop_label_box2.addWidget(pic_laybel)

            for i in range(7):      # заполнение едитами 1 формы
                edit_ = QLineEdit()
                edit_.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
                edit_.setMaximumSize(45, 30)
                edit_.setValidator(val)
                edit_.setMaxLength(4)
                pop_le_box.addWidget(edit_)

            for i in range(7):      # заполнение едитами 2 формы
                edit_ = QLineEdit()
                edit_.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
                edit_.setMaximumSize(45, 30)
                edit_.setValidator(val)
                edit_.setMaxLength(4)
                pop_le_box2.addWidget(edit_)

            la_le_box.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, pop_label_box)
            la_le_box.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, pop_le_box)
            la_le_box2.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, pop_label_box2)
            la_le_box2.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, pop_le_box2)

            buttons_form.addLayout(self.stacked_form_box)
            main_box.addLayout(buttons_form,0,0,1,1)

        _consumptiontab(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPD:** Нашел ответ на свой вопрос:
[QStackedWidget opening multiple windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203087/qstackedwidget-opening-multiple-windows)

Comment: Так Вы изначально задаете два окна?

Comment: @CATpython Изначально у меня одно окно. Ну если я правильно понимаю, то эти 2 виджета которые создаются, они вставляются QStackedLayout который в свою очередь вставляется в другой макет и т.д. до центрального виджета. Не могу понять почему виджеты создаются отдельным окном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, в вашем коде много суеты.
Я предложу вам попробовать мой вариант реализации вашей идеи.
Обратите внимание я использую виджет `QStackedWidget` вместо `QStackedLayout` 
и думаю, что ваша проблема исчезнет, если вы в своеи коде сделаете
такую же замену и заменете строку

```
buttons_form.addLayout(self.stacked_form_box)
```

на строку

```
buttons_form.addWidget(self.stacked_form_box)
```

Проверьте и свой и мой вариант.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget") 
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        self.main_layout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        self.stacked_form_box = QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_form_box.setObjectName("stacked_form_box")  
 
        self.people_btn = QPushButton(QIcon('Ok.png'), '')
        self.people_btn.setFixedSize(40, 40)
        self.people_btn.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35))
        self.people_btn.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.stacked_form_box.setCurrentIndex(0))        

        self.house_btn = QPushButton(QIcon('im.png'), '')        
        self.house_btn.setFixedSize(40, 40)
        self.house_btn.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35))
        self.house_btn.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.stacked_form_box.setCurrentIndex(1)) 
        
        self.page = QFrame()
        self.page.setMinimumSize(200, 300)
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.pageUi(self.page, "Ok.png", "page_1_")
        self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.page)
        
        self.page_2 = QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.pageUi(self.page_2, "im.png", "page_2_")
        self.stacked_form_box.addWidget(self.page_2)
        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.people_btn, 1, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignRight)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.house_btn, 1, 2, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.stacked_form_box, 2, 1, 2, 2)
        self.main_layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.main_layout.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        self.main_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.main_layout.setColumnStretch(4, 1)
        
    def pageUi(self, parent, path, page):
        layout = QFormLayout(parent)    
        for i in range(7):
            pic_laybel = QLabel()
            pic_laybel.setPixmap(QPixmap(path).scaled(30, 30))
            lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            lineEdit.setObjectName(f'{page}{i}')
            lineEdit.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
            layout.addRow(pic_laybel, lineEdit)
 
QSS = '''
#centralwidget {
    background-color: #313552;
}
#page {
    background-color: #B8405E;
}
#page_2 {
    background-color: #2EB086;
}
'''      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(220, 350)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**im.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите, в чем разница QStackedLayout и QStackedWidget? В документации их описание идентичное. Но в моём понимании QStackedLayout и предназначен для компоновки виджетов

Comment: @Rett_oo  вы проверили то что я вам предложил? То что я вам предложил, решает вашу проблему?

Comment: Да, проблему решает.

Comment: @Rett_oo  sorry, на SO есть вопросы с корректной реализацией QStackedLayout изучите их. У меня просто нет времени анализировать ваш код, поэтому я и предложил свой вариант.